# Set innerHTML of an unattached iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there any way to set the innerHTML of an iframe that is not attached to the DOM?

Currently when doing this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var doc =  iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
doc.body.innerHTML = 'hi';
```

I get the following Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null

I understand this.  But is there a way to generate the document element, or set the data of the iframe without having to attach it to the DOM?

Comment: It has to be attached to the DOM to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any future readers, I found what I was looking for here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument

It allows you to create a document object, make changes to it and insert it into an `<iframe>` when ready.